# Can't install <package_name>.tar.gz: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_version'

Tags: python, pip, distutils, python-packaging, python-wheel

I have a problem to install packages like `configobj` or `version` with pip. So commands like `pip install configobj` lead to following outputs:

```
Collecting configobj>=5.0.5
  Using cached configobj-5.0.6.tar.gz (33 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\alfeil\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g4gjt2rb\configobj_1edeed4e30c44f45bbb715635d30e829\setup.py", line 17, in <module>
          from _version import __version__
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_version'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
```

I tried many approaches that I found on the internet, but I could not solve this problem. Maybe I missing some dependencies.

I am using **Python: 3.10.5** and **pip: 22.3**

Here is the output of `pip list`

```
Package            Version
------------------ -----------
beautifulsoup4     4.11.1
certifi            2022.9.24
charset-normalizer 2.1.1
colorama           0.4.5
download-tarball   0.0.7
ez-setup           0.9
idna               3.4
importlib-metadata 5.0.0
pip                22.3
pypiwin32          223
pywin32            304
requests           2.28.1
setuptools         65.5.0
six                1.16.0
soupsieve          2.3.2.post1
tqdm               4.64.1
urllib3            1.26.12
zipp               3.9.0
```

It want to mention that the installation of `configobj` and other packages in tar.gz format runs on standard Windows Python installation (version 3.10.5) without errors (installation via exe).

But I need to install Python via embeddable zip files locally for my project. So if I run e.g. `python -m pip install configobj`, the above errors appears.

Probably I am missing a dependencies to install packages with tar.gz format. Maybe it is a library or somethings else.

Comment: Seems like this project is packaged with `distutils` (not `setuptools`). Not sure it has an influence here or not. -- Also you might want to be more explicit about what you mean here: "_It would like to mention that the installation runs on standard Python installation (version 3.10.5) without errors. But I have to install Python over embeddable zip files and there are errors with all tar.gz packages (like configobj)._" Is it about installing Python itself. Or about installing libraries?

Comment: It is about installing libraries

Comment: Where did you get the `tar.gz` files from? Please edit your question to remove the irrelevant parts and add the relevant parts... If it happens with all libraries and not just `configobj`, please do say clearly so in the question (and remove the `configobj` tag). Check if it happens with all Python interpreter versions, with all pip versions, and so on... try to narrow it down as much as possible. -- Maybe try to build a wheelhouse instead of relying on sdists.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like the configobj project supports python 3.10 or 3.9 or 3.8...
https://github.com/DiffSK/configobj#status

Comment: But why it runs on standard Python installation (Version 3.10.5)?